# How to discover Object APIs in the Node.js console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The Canary Developer Tools offer great features like `console.table` and `console.dir` which give details about the various functions and properties available on an object.

I'd like to know if this is somehow possible in the Node.js REPL. I've tried a few combinations that work great in the browser developer tools:

```
> console.dir(Promise)
[Function: Promise]
undefined
> console.log(Promise)
[Function: Promise]
undefined
> Promise
[Function: Promise]
> console.table(Promise)
TypeError: console.table is not a function
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:248:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

How do I get access and documentation about these functions and more inside Node without having to open MDN or Node.js docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of `Promise`'s properties are non-enumerable and are therefore hidden by default from Node's logging. You can use the [`showHidden` option of Node's `console.dir`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options) to show them:

> `showHidden` - if `true` then the object's non-enumerable and symbol properties will be shown too. Defaults to `false`.

When you run `console.dir(Promise, { showHidden: true })` you'll see all the properties of the object.

Comment: Hmm,`> console.dir(String, {showHidden: true})` gives me `TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a number`.